# Request Download Link Using My Server IP

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to build application using the Openload API https://openload.co/api#download-ticket

I'm using PHP curl to parse JSON file and download the file. below are my codes:

```
$url = 'https://api.openload.co/1/file/dl?file=svctclysb7u&ticket=SvCtcLYsB7U&captcha_response=ty32';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

if ($response !== false) {

    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($json['status'] === 200) {
        header('Location: ' . $json['result']['url']);
    }
}
```

So I;m trying to redirect to the download url using header('Location' . $json['result']['url']) but I get this error:

```
download ISP is different to request ISP. request: AS55293 download: AS9299
```

I tried to research and found out that the download request is coming from my server IP and then downloading using my ISP IP which is a issue for openload.

Is there a way to trick the API that I'm using the same ISP to download the file? or atleast any way to make the download process to be on the same ISP?

I already tried using ajax and $.getJson but no luck and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the request using AJAX on the client side, and then redirect the user to make the download themselves. However this is bad practice and can get you banned from using the API, so I would suggest against that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with requesting using AJAX on client side. do you mean $.getJSON? can you point to some reference or guide?

Comment: I'd rather use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) directly, but here's [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: as I mentioned above, I already tried using $.getJson. The result is the same. I suspect that its because the $.getJson is requesting the Json from API from the server side.

Comment: You will have to make the request to the openload API directly from the client side, not through your server.

Comment: So here is my code: 
$(function(){
 $.getJSON('https://api.openload.co/1/file/dl?file=svctclysb7u&ticket=SvCtcLYsB7U&captcha_response=ty32', function(data) {
        window.location.href = data.result.url;
 });
 });